# Loading time of Wijmo Menu Scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wijmo

I am using this menus http://wijmo.com/widgets/wijmo-open/menu/ , its working ok but i have this problem:

Takes some time to load the js files and the menu show up  like a tree and after some seconds the menu is ok.

How can i speed up the loading or do something to dont show the tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the online demo using the latest version 2.3.7 available at the below link:
http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/?widget=Menu&sample=Overview

and the menu did show up without any delay. Could you kindly check the same ?
If the issue persists then let me know the browser details and the version which you are using.

Regards

Comment: that is what i want, but isn't right that. maybe some configuration. this is what happend to me http://screencast.com/t/QZVostDom8C

Comment: I assume you are facing this issue in IE9. This is a known issue and a workaround has been discussed in the following forum link: http://wijmo.com/topic/slow-browser-refresh-causing-wijmenu-issue/

Comment: Found the issue. Forget to add this class 'ui-helper-hidden-accessible' and this part of the javascript j('#flyoutmenu').removeClass('ui-helper-hidden-accessible');